# facebook sdk api and nativeoffers

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have problem with creating facebook page offer. It return ID of post, but i can not find it on facebook.
I found information only here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/native-offer/
But when i creating it on facebook, it require a photo. Photo url is not included in source

```
$params = array(
'location_type' => 'both',
'discounts' => array(
    array(
        'type' => 'percentage_off',
        'text' => 'the text description for this offer',
        'value1' => 20,
    ),

),
'redemption_link' => 'www.link.com',
'redemption_code' => 'happysummer2016',
'details' => 'the details for this specific offer',
'expiration_time' => (new \DateTime("+10 day"))->getTimestamp(),
);

$pages=getPages($fb);
foreach ($pages as $key) {
if ($key['name'] == 'name') {
    $post = $fb->post('/' . $key['id'] . '/nativeoffers', $params, $key['access_token']);
    $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    print_r($post);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A "native offer" is not visible on a Facebook page, you need to make a "native offer view". The native offer is the rules that govern the offer, the native offer view is the visible component that users interact with. More here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/native-offer/

Comment: How it is possible to create? native-offer/views: Creating
You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Comment: Hi Pavel, sorry, added the correct link. See the section under "You can make a POST request to nativeofferviews edge from the following paths:
/{native_offer_id}/nativeofferviews"